# Use a command inside sed

Tags: linux, sed

The purpose of the command should be replacing any IP in file `myfile.txt` with the local ip of the server automatically

example:

```
sed -i -e 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/LOCALIP/g' myfile.txt
```

i want to know if it possible to use command for getting local ip address inside sed

basically i want to replace `LOCALIP` in my example with this command

```
/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my issue with this command

```
sed -i "s/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/$(ifconfig | grep 'inet ' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '{print $2}')/" myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use command substitution in double quotes:

```
sed -i -e 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/'"$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)/g" myfile.txt
```

In single quotes, this won't work, so end the single quotes before `LOCALIP`, use double quotes for the command. This way, we don't accidentally do expansions in the search pattern.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer, got this error : sed: -e expression #1, char 71: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Are you sure the command to get IP is executing correctly? What output do you get with `/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)`? Also, try putting an `echo` before `sed` to see what sed command is finally run.

Comment: Got this output with /sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1): 207.154.202.52
10.19.0.6

Comment: @JeffSchaller but `"$(...)"/g` and `"$(...)/g"` should both give the same string, shouldn't it?

Comment: Appears the OP has a space - separated list of *two* IP's coming back from that command, causing the sed command to end early.

Comment: @jeff-schaller your replay has solved my problem this is the working command sed -i "s/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/$(ifconfig | grep 'inet ' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '{print $2}')/" myfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked fine for me

```
sed "s/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)/"
```