# sed error unterminated `s' command

Tags: linux, sed

The purpose of the command should be replacing any IP in file `myfile.txt` with the local IP of the server automatically

i tried to use this command:

```
sed -i -e 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/'"$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)/g" myfile.txt
```

but got this error

```
 sed: -e expression #1, char 71: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: What's the output of the command substitution? What do you see when you run this with `set -x` enabled?

Comment: This question is almost identical to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483226/use-a-command-inside-sed, did you perhaps create another account?

Comment: The answer on that original had a typo; vtc as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Command:

Use below command i Tested and it worked  fine

```
sed "s/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/`/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1`/" filename
```